# Fitting a dampening coefficient and computing a Fourier transform at the same time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, fourier-series

I have a brief mono audio sample (a recording of a single note played on a guitar) that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the signal is losing intensity over time. My goal is to quantify **the rate of decay** of this note, i.e. how quickly it is losing intensity. I can do this heuristically, e.g. by taking the ratio between the first and last peak, but this approach is not very robust because it only uses two of the sample points and is thus highly sensitive to random noise.

If possible, I'd like to "divide out" the oscillation component of the signal (probably using a Fourier transform) and then fit an exponential decay equation to the result. This approach would make use of the entire audio sample, and therefore be less sensitive to error in an individual sample point. However, I do not know if this approach is viable, and I don't understand the details of how to carry this out.

### My attempt

We know from differential equations that the position of a [damped harmonic oscillator](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html#c2) is given by (after scaling and translation)

$$x(t) = \exp(-\lambda t) \sin( \omega t),$$

where $\lambda$ is a damping coefficient and $\omega$ is the frequency. So, one idea is to fit the equation above to my input data (e.g. using least squares). But a guitar string doesn't oscillate at just one frequency $\omega$—my input signal is really the composite of several frequencies, which depend on the physical properties of the string and guitar body. To get frequency components from time series data, we normally use a (discrete, in this case) Fourier transform.

**I'm stuck because it seems like I need to fit a damped harmonic oscillator model and perform a Fourier transform simultaneously.** I know how to do these tasks individually, but not at the same time.

### My questions

- Is there a standard way to estimate the decay coefficient from time series data like this?
- Can it done programmatically? (That is, in a way that doesn't require manually labeling peaks, specifying the fundamental frequency, etc.)

---

I have seen references online to something called RT60 estimation, used to quantify how much sound decays in a room, but this seems like a somewhat different problem: There, the problem is to integrate impulse response data sampled from many different places in the room, whereas I have just a single time series and no notion of place within the room.

Comment: I do not know if this is the 'correct' way, but if $x(t)=\exp(-\lambda t)\sin(\omega_0 t)$ (for $t\geq 0$ and $0$ else), then the FT is $\tilde{x}(\omega)\propto \omega_0((\lambda-i\omega)^2+\omega_0^2)^{-1}$, so that's what you'd be fitting to your Fourier transformed data to determine $\lambda$ and $\omega_0$

Comment: The problem is that my frequency isn't a single dampened sine wave. It has several component frequencies.

Comment: Each component frequency $\omega_k$ will then contribute a term $\tilde{x}_k(\omega) \propto \omega_k((\lambda_k-i\omega)^2+\omega_k^2)^{-1}$ to the FT. Each peak in the FT will represent an $\omega_k$ and the width of each peak will be related to $\lambda_k$. The overall spectrum should then be $\tilde{x}(\omega)=\sum\limits_kA_k\ \tilde{x}_k(\omega)$

Comment: Right, but how do I decide how many and which frequencies to choose? I get the general picture, but my question is about the particulars. Ideally, I want an algorithm that just takes the sound sample as input—without me telling it magic numbers like the fundamental frequency—and fits the decay coefficient. (Or if this is impossible, some insight into why the problem is hard.)

Comment: Just spitballing, but another approach might be to multiply the signal by an exponential *growth* function $\exp(\lambda t)$. If $\lambda$ matches the decay coefficient, then the resulting signal will have constant strength instead of decaying or growing. So if there is an easy way to measure the "consistency" of the signal strength over time, you could line search on $\lambda$ for the value that maximizes the consistency. But the obvious consistency measures, e.g. the rolling average of $x(t)^2$, introduce new parameters (rolling window size) that you would have to choose heuristically.

Comment: Oh I see: you are presuming that each mode has an identical decay coefficient! In this case we should be able to make progress- I will think about it

Comment: Maybe too simple, but I would calculate the momentary power for each sample $x^2[k]$, and then LSE fit the decay curve to it. Make that $e^{-2\lambda t}$ because you work with power instead of amplitudes.

Comment: I assume you mean, "replace each length-$k$ slice of the sample with the average value of $x_t^2$ over that sample, then fit the decay curve," right? How do you decide on the value of $k$? If $k$ happens to align with the period of one of the fundamental frequencies, couldn't this generate weird artifacts?

Comment: No, just square each sample and that's it. If you have a sum of two cosines $A[k]\left(\cos(ak)+\cos(bk)\right)$ then you get $\frac{1}{2}A^2[k]\left(1+\cos(2ak)+\cos(2bk)+2\cos((a+b)k)+2\cos((a-b)k)\right)$. That would give you the square of the slow decay function $A[k]$ multiplied by a constant plus some zero mean-functions. The zero-mean functions should not  bother a fitting algorithm. Not exact science, a suggested approach :-)

Comment: I have now experimented with this approach, but ran into a problem when $x_t = x_t^2 = 0$. Normally, to fit the model $x = a \exp( \lambda t)$, you would take the log on both sides so that the equation is linear in the parameters $\lambda$ and $b := \log a$, but you can't take the log when $x = 0$. So, I tried minimizing $(x - a \exp( \lambda t))^2$ instead, but due to the large number of zeros, the minimum is unattainable—just cranking $\lambda$ really high decreases the objective value.

Comment: You might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93frequency_analysis_for_music_signals.

Comment: What about this forum? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=fourier+analysis+